# sorting arrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a scenario where I have two ArrayLists

```
ArrayList<String> sortedArrayList
ArrayList<String> unSortedArrayList
```

I have to sort unSortedArrayList depending on the sortedArrayList.

i.e, sortedArrayList is already sorted, now based on sortedArrayList, I have to sort unSortedArrayList.

```
unSortedArrayList size is <= to the size of sortedArrayList.
```

Is there a Java API for that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean 'based on'? You mean the same kind of sort? If both the lists are sorted identically, you can as well use the other one and trim it by a few elements.

Comment: What do you mean by "based on"? It's incredibly unclear what you mean. An example would be very helpful.

Comment: I imagine he means that he wants to use the elements' order in `sortedArrayList` as a sorting order for the other list

Comment: here is an eg. sortedArrayList={"a","a1","a2","a3","a4"}; unSortedArrayList={"a2","a","a1","a4"};

Comment: @user: is it possible that `unsortedArrayList` contains a value that is **not** present in `sortedArrayList` or is it a strict subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        List<String> newSortedList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String currentSortedStr:sortedList){

            if(unsortedList.size==0)break;

            if(unsortedList.remove(currentSortedStr)){
                newSortedList.add(currentSortedStr);
            }
        }
```

You can do something like this if you mean what @Sam Dufel says in the comment

As far as I know there is not such API method for this case.

This is not gonna take care of duplicates. remove will remove only the first occurence of that object. At the if the unsorted list size is greater than 0, you can say it contains duplicates. And if you need duplicates as well, you may wanna add some code to handle that case as well.

or if you mean the normal sorting;

`Collections.sort(List<T>)`  will do the sorting for you.

Another way of doing it;

```
Collections.sort(unsortedList,new CustomComparator(sortedList));

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>{
        private List<String> sortedList;
        public CustomComparator(List<String> sortedList){
            this.sortedList = sortedList;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return sortedList.indexOf(o1)-sortedList.indexOf(o2);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: The other way of doing it will be very slow because of all these `indexOf` calls. The guava way is better ;)

Comment: @sjr Comparing to the first one, yes you are right, second one will be slower than 1st. However, I should say sequential memory reading is pretty fast. If not tens of thoundsands of objects exists in the sortedlist, difference will probably be ignorable.

Comment: This might be `O(n^2 log n)` at worst because you may have to traverse the whole list for every comparison. Your solution will work with a handful of elements but may not with tens or hundreds of thousands.

Comment: how did you calculate n^2 log n? I see it will be (n log n) at worst case

Comment: `indexOf` is a linear search, so another `n` for each comparison, `n lg n` comparisons, `n*n log n = n^2 log n`

Comment: @fmucar-- Could you please throw few lines to handle duplicates as well on your first example. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s excellent [Ordering](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class:

```
Collections.sort(unSortedArrayList, Ordering.explicit(sortedArrayList));
```

*EDIT* You can also do

```
List<whatever> sortedList = Ordering.explicit(sortedArrayList).immutableSortedCopy(unsortedArrayList);
```

Comment: +1 from me as well, if the process is worth adding a new library to the classpath

Answer (score 2):

As I understand what you have is that each element in list 1 has a corresponding element in list 2, and you want list 2 sorted into the order of the 'corresponding' elements. Your best approach is to create an object to contain both Strings:

```
class StringPair {
  String s1;
  String s2;
}
```

Now make an array list of StringPairs and sort it based on the value of s1.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not clear enough I think that the following will help you.

You can use `Collections.sort()` to sort list. If you need some custom modification to sort mechanism implement your own `Comparator` and use 2 args version of this method: `Collections.sort(list, comparable)`